# UDP Server and Client Failing to Send And Recieve Messages

Tags: python, sockets

I am building a simple network chat in Python using UDP, however, when I run the server code on one machine and the client on another, no message is received by the server and no message is sent back to the client by the server script. Here is my code:

Server:

```
import socket, sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock.bind(('', 9997)) #need higher port

while True:

    x = raw_input("Enter your message: ")
    sent = sock.sendto(x, ('', 9997))
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    print data, " ", address

sock.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    print "Waiting to receive"
    data, server = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    print data
    x = raw_input("Enter message: ")
    sent = sock.sendto(x, server)

sock.close()
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Is is possible that code is fine, but the UDP is not reliable enough and is dropping the message?

Comment: Where are you specifying the hostname/ip address of the client and the server?

Comment: In the server script, I used `' '` as the hostname, as I read that will tell the server to look on all available ports. In my client, I send my response back to the address that is sent by the server.

Comment: Is it just me or did you swap Client and Server?

Comment: I am not sure, you could be right though. I will test.

Comment: And I'm not convinced about the ports. According to what I see, Client receives data from port 4096 and sends back to the server. The server is sending data to port 9997 though, so Client will never receive anything on 4096

Comment: I just tested, and when I run the Client code as the server and attempt to send the message via the server, all I get is an echo of what I sent.

Comment: @magicleon So you are saying that 4096 is actually being specified as a port?

Comment: I'm saying that both 4096 and 9997 are specified as ports, but I think they're used in a wrong way. I'm on mobile right now (going home lol), I could check better when I'll be in front of my pc. But I'm pretty sure you're just sending traffic (or receiving, or both) to (from) the wrong ports

Comment: @magicleon That makes sense. What do you suggest I change the port numbers to?

Comment: The hostname/IP address of the other app has to be used by one or the other to send the first message, then the other replies to where it received from. To be specific, `sock.sendto(x, ('', 9997))` probably sends only to localhost.

Comment: And to answer your question about UDP, on a local wired network UDP packets should work 99.99...% of the time, i.e. definitely not 0% of the time as you are seeing.

Comment: Ok, good to know.

Comment: I will specify an IP where I first put `' '` and see if that works.

Comment: uops, `recvFrom` takes the buffer size as an argument, sorry my bad

Comment: By the way I wrote a working example. Since you're learning, I think a fresh start is better than keeping watching this, and it's very similar. I'm posting it as an answer.

Comment: That would be great, thanks!

Comment: Done, thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, since your code seems a little unclear (to me, at least), I'm posting you a very similar working example. 
Here's the **Server**:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 1932)
sock.bind(server_address)

BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
try:
    while True:
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print "Client sends: ", data
        reply = raw_input("Your response:\n")
        sock.sendto(reply,address)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sock.close()
```

The server creates a socket and binds it to its address and the port it's listening to, 1932 in our case. He waits for an incoming message, asks for a reply, then sends it back to the sender.

 Here's the **Client**:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client_address = ('localhost', 1931)

server_address = ('localhost', 1932)

sock.bind(client_address)

BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
try:
    first_msg = raw_input("Your first message:\n")
    sock.sendto(first_msg,server_address)
    while True:
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print "Client sends: ", data
        reply = raw_input("Your response:\n")
        sock.sendto(reply,address)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sock.close()
```

It's very similar to the server, the only difference is that it sends a message **before** the `while` loop, in order to start the conversation. Then it just enters the `receive/reply` loop, just as the server does. It has the server address too, that is different (different port, since I'm on localhost) 
The `try/catch` block is here just to close gracefully the whole process.

 I used `localhost` and different ports on my computer and tested it, and it works. You should just change the addresses to get it working over LAN, and you could keep the same port if the addresses are different, it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: That was a pleasure!